# How to run a circuit with both 5V and 3V3 supply voltage?

Tags: microcontroller, power, st

I'm currently designing a circuit requiring 3V3 (an ARM MCU) which should run on both 5V and 3V3 input.

Since the power requirements are fairly low, a linear voltage regulator should suffice.

I want to use [L78L33](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78l.pdf) but I cannot find information regarding the voltage drop and minimum voltage requirement. Especially the graphs on page 26 only specify output characteristics of L78L05/12/24 but not L78L33.

Which regulator can be used to provide 3V3 with input voltage as low as 3V3?

Comment: The typical voltage drop **is** specified in the tables of electrical characteristics, but only a typical value is provided. I think if you look at this you will be able to answer your own question about using the 78L33.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson thank you very much for the feedback! Since only three voltages in the electrical characteristics provides a typical value, I assume the property you are referring to is V_d (Dropout Voltage). I did assume that this is not the voltage drop but the minimum required input voltage for an output voltage to be available at all. Is this assumption not correct?

Comment: @ooxi the trick is that most MCUs don't need to be supplied with *exactly* 3.3 V, but some can work down to 2.8 V, too. So, just as peufeu recommend, use a different linear regulator (an LDO), and maybe use 3.0 V as supply voltage to your MCU.

Comment: The dropout voltage is the **difference** between the input voltage and the output voltage. With a typical dropout of 2V, the regulator will (typically) need 5.3V in to provide 3.3V out.

Comment: Thanks @ElliotAlderson! At some point I assumed that was the case but it's great having it spelled out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

78Lxx Datasheet does show dropout vs current:

[image]

Note the 78Lxx (and 78xx) series chips set output voltage via their internal feedback resistor divider (see datasheet p. 3, R10/R11 on schematic) which is pretty much the only difference between all the output voltage variants in the series. So it is safe to assume the dropout voltage from 78L05 on the graph will be the same for 78L33.

**EDIT:** I should have read the datasheet a bit better. It's only a typical value,  there is no maximum dropout specified, and both 3.3V and 5V versions spec 2V typical dropout in the characteristics table, which disagrees with the graph.

So you'll have to use a LDO like [this one](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ldl1117.pdf).

If you have two different power inputs for 3.3V and 5V then you can route the 5V input through a regulator to make 3.3V, and route the 3.3V input directly to the circuit, bypassing the regulator. Then use the appropriate power input. This is the best solution.

If you have only one power input then you'll need a regulator with very low dropout voltage. Losing 50-100mV on 3.3V shouldn't be too much of a problem (check the datasheet of your micro and other chips you use for allowed voltage range, and pay special attention if you use VCC as ADC reference).

You can filter and sort LDOs by dropout voltage on [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-linear/699?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv2065=8623&pv2065=8374&pv2065=9509&pv2065=9358&pv2065=14026&pv2065=14027&pv2065=14030&pv2065=14033&pv2065=14037&pv2065=14042&pv2065=14043&pv2065=14045&sf=0&FV=ii1%7C1065%2C1779%7C174115%2C2065%7C14026%2C2065%7C14027%2C2065%7C14030%2C2065%7C14033%2C2065%7C14037%2C2065%7C14042%2C2065%7C14043%2C2065%7C14045%2C2065%7C5682%2C2065%7C7205%2C2065%7C7512%2C2065%7C8374%2C2065%7C8623%2C2065%7C9358%2C2065%7C9509%2C-8%7C699&quantity=&ColumnSort=2065&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25).

However, be aware that a 3V3 LDO which is powered from 3V3 will be in dropout mode, it will not regulate the output voltage. It will essentially be a fully turned on FET in series with the supply, ie pretty much a resistor, without any PSRR or voltage regulation.

Vocabulary notes:

1) Dropout voltage is the minimum difference between input voltage and output voltage to maintain proper regulation according to datasheet specs.

2) When the regulator is "in dropout" it means the difference between input and output voltage is too low for it to properly regulate. The output voltage will drop below spec, and the pass transistor will be saturated (if it's a BJT) or fully turned on and behave like a resistor (if it's a FET). The error amp will also be clipped. In this state the LDO no longer functions and does not honor its specifications, there is no regulation and PSRR is non-existent.

Comment: But isn't the 78L05 supposed to output 5V instead of 3V3? Or is it sufficient to assume the 70L33 will behave similarly?

Comment: Yeah they will have the same dropout, I've added a paragraph on that.

Comment: But they **do not** have the same dropout! The datasheet gives a typical dropout for the 5V part of 1.7V while the dropout for the 3.3V part is 2.0V. Providing 5.0V to the input of the regulator will only give a **typical** overhead of 1.7V...less than the typical required by the 3.3V regulator. If the 5V regulator is at the low end of its output range it will actually provide 4.6V and the overhead drops to 1.3V. This is not good advice.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Oops, corrected. Thanks!

Comment: @peufeu thank you very much for providing such a great answer! I my opinion it could be improved by including the definition of dropout voltage as described by Elliot Alderson. I now understand the characteristics but it might be helpful for future readers :-)